# Какой язык выбрать для написания ботов

Tags: бот

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите язык для написания ботов для игр.
Требуемые функции:
 - Определение текущего статуса. Т.е. допустим чтобы можно было сравнивать скрин с текущим положением в игре. Т.е. допустим определить, идёт ли игра, либо пользователь в меню.

Comment: "определение текущего статуса" - очень широкое понятие. Плюс не указанно, что за игра - это может быть и веб, и полноэкранная игра и игра на телефоне.

По существу - выбирайте любой декстопный язык - python, c++, java. php хуже подойдет. А вот для веб игр может очень хорошо подойти javascript.

Но одно важно - сами по себе языки плохо решают подобные задачи - нужно искать хорошие фреймворки.

Comment: @temagr, тот, которым Вы хорошо владеете (написали на нем много разнообразных программ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По скрину определять - не совсем удачная идея. Потому как зная основы крекинга, можно сделать куда больше и проще. Вообщем, если хочешь этим серьезно заняться, то как вариант выбирай asm и C/C++, пройдись по основам того и другого, а потом ищи на этом [сайте](http://www.cracklab.ru/)
статьи, видео уроки и т.д, только сильно не разменивайся на все, основ будет достаточно для начала, если хочешь быстрый старт. И пробуй сделать что-то простенькое, а потом уже углубляйся в то, что нужно будет. То есть, найди какую-нибудь интересующую игру к которой есть хаки с исходным кодом и дальше уже по ним учись делать свои.

Answer (score 3):

Пиши на python. Скорость разработки, а также всякие плюшки упростят эту задачу.

Comment: Так я питонист ) Просто я не знаю в сторону каких модулей мне смотреть.

Answer (score 2):

Как насчёт **[Sikuli](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikuli)**

Answer (score 2):

В java есть всё что надо:умеет делать скрины (можно реализовать пиксельный контроль), есть также функции для передвижения курсора, нажатия кнопок. Когда-то писал на java нечто подобное.

Comment: то, что вы перечислили, можно точно так же реализовать средствами практически любого языка

Comment: тогда уж C++ и WinAPI

Comment: @shkiper тогда уж без плюсов. Или на ассемблере. И на win32api -- под линукс (под wine'ом).

Comment: >под линукс (под wine'ом)
а зачем?

Comment: @strol наращивание абсурда. Вопрос, как всегда (почти) с неконкретными условиями, советы примерно соответствуют вопросу, так что надо повышать градус дискуссии, пока ТС не сознается, что же именно ему надо.

@temagr считает, что вопрос вполне однозначно определяет ситуацию. Но, возможно, тут просто эффект студента (который как собака -- всё понимает, но сказать не может)

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать LUA 5.1

вот из википедии:

> Язык широко используется для создания тиражируемого программного обеспечения — в частности, на нём написан графический интерфейс пакета Adobe Lightroom. Также получил известность как язык программирования уровней и расширений во многих играх (например, World of Warcraft) из-за удобства встраивания, скорости исполнения кода и лёгкости обучения.